# What is the earliest example of LLMs used for AI in hard-sci-fiction before 2018?

Tags: history-of, artificial-intelligence, hard-sci-fi

All the AI in fiction, and none that I came across thought it could be helped by brute-forcing language in statistical models.

What is the earliest example of large language models or something similar being used in Science Fiction from before GPT arrived on the scene (before 2018)?

Comment: Right now this seems a bit open ended. I would change this to something like "the earliest example of use of large language models in Sci Fi." It is a more accepted question form on here, it allows the answer to be a bit more targeted, and it gives the answer more trivia value.

Comment: Maybe Shalmaneser, the supercomputer in "Stand on Zanzibar" (1968). At least this one is connected to all news and entertainment streams on the planet and synthesizes the available information into answers to all kind of queries (however I don't think it is explicitly described as using something LLM-like).

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff ! I will have a look at that.

Comment: What would you consider "similar" to a LLM?  How would you establish that similarity from a textual description?  And what if there aren't any previous to 2018, will you accept an answer from 2019?

Comment: Would an AI model merely trained on a corpus of text count for the purposes of the question? (See eg "[Be Right Back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Be_Right_Back)" from Black Mirror S2.)

Comment: @DavidW Something from 2019 would indeed be noteworthy.

Comment: I remember a science fiction story from the late-70's, early 80's (probably in Omni), that featured the first AI that consisted of billions of artificial neurons that was trained kind of blindly on a large corpus of data, so it had many similarities with LLMs.  Can not for the life of me remember the title or author-- maybe someone else could?  I bellieve the device in the story was suppose to be an upgraded version of the real-life Connection Machine (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_Machine)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but the 1963 Philip K. Dick short story [If There Were No Benny Cemoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_There_Were_No_Benny_Cemoli) prominently features a *homeostatic newspaper* or *homeopape* (actually a future version of the New York Times), which gathers up news from across the world via "receptors" and compiles it in human-readable newspaper editions every day. A quote from the story:

> An hour later a ship of the line had landed in the vicinity and its
> power source had been tapped for insertion into the homeopape. The
> conduits were placed, the circuits cautiously closed.
>
> Seated in his office, Peter Hood heard far underground a low rumble, a
> halting, uncertain stirring. They had been successful. The newspaper
> was returning to life.
>
> The edition, when it was laid on his desk by a bustling CURBman,
> surprised him by its accuracy. Even in its dormant state, the
> newspaper had somehow managed not to fall behind events. Its receptors
> had kept going.
>
> CURB LANDS, TRIP DECADE LONG,
>
> PLANS CENTRAL ADMINISTRATION

Comment: There is no evidence that this is using a LLM, and indeed it's far too early for that idea to possibly be applicable.

Comment: @DavidW: but interesting and prophetic as usual on PKD's part. I wish he had lived to see, for example, BR2049, how thrilled he would have been.